# virt-manager does not display BIOS or grub during boot

Tags: kvm-virtualization, virt-manager

I've inherited some KVM machines and I do not know how these were configured.

I'm trying to access the VM's console. I've successfully opened virt-manager and found the console button available from that tool. This does, indeed, open a window of any running machine and displays the contents of the machine console.

However, during reboot, the screen remains blank until it has finished booting at which point the main login prompt is displayed. I miss BIOS, grub, and the rest of the boot process.

How do I connect to a more complete console?

virt-manager 0.9.5
QEMU emulator 2.0.0

I'm displaying on Win7 using XServer XMing 7.5.0.93